# Convert '00:00' to '00:00:00' pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that has a column with time data like ['25:45','12:34:34'], the initial idea is: first convert this column to a list called "time_list". Then with a for, iterate and convert it to minutes

```
time_list = df7[' Chip Time'].tolist()

time_mins = []
for i in time_list:
    h, m, s = i.split(':')
    math = (int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s))/60
    time_mins.append(math)
```

But I got this error: ValueError: too many values ​​to unpack... . It is because within the data there are values ​​of only minutes and seconds but also others with hours, minutes and seconds.

My idea is to convert this column into a single format, that of 'hh:mm:ss' but I can't find the way. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Please translate into English.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not in english. Questions on so need to be in english.

Comment: Hola, Josue. https://es.stackoverflow.com/ es para preguntas en espanol.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `h, m, s = i.split(':')` you should be using `t = i.split(':')` because the first expects the `i.split` to always return 3 values, but in cases where `i = [aa:bb]` it will only return two. From there you use the length of t to decide if you need to calculate the seconds or not.

Your code is converting everything to seconds and could be replaced with something like this:

```
t = i.split(':')
for i in range(len(t)):
    math += t[i] * 3600 ** (1./(60 ** i))
    # 3600 ** (1./(60 ** i)) returns 3600, 60, 1 for i = 0, 1, 2
time_mins.append(math)
```

but if your goal is just to append :00 to any entry that dosen't have seconds then you could just do this:

```
t = i.split(':')
if len(t) == 2:
    time_mins.append(str(i)+":00")
else:
    time_mins.append(i)
```

Comment: Thak you for  you response.
In your code (t = i.split(':')), i have a problem: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'"

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
I reformatted that column with a function:

1. Creating function

```
def format_date(n):
    if len(n) == 5:
        return "{}:{}:{}".format('00', n[0:2], n[3:5])
    else:
        return n**
```

2. Applying in that column with labda:

```
df7['ChipTime'] = df7.apply(lambda x: format_date(x.ChipTime), axis=1)
df7
```

and done. Thank you.